# Extract attachments from .MSG to use them in a PHP application

Tags: php

I'm developing a PHP driven web application and i need to extract attachments from Outlook .msg. I haven't wondered outside PHP, Python and adjacent web languages so please take me easy.
If one is curious the task is to check an email address, get the body and attachments and add them to the DMS.
I'm googling for hours now and i see there is no easy way (like a PHP class or similar) so any workaround would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Outlook MSG files are actually [COM Structured Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage). You might be able to read them using [PEAR OLE](http://pear.php.net/package/OLE). But, the page claims it is unmaintained.

Keep in mind that even if you manage to open the document, you will need to understand its internal layout to be able to find anything. [FileFormats](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/) appears to list some useful internal information you might want to keep handy as a reference as you are exploring the MSG file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we have decided to use a .msg extractor (http://e-viewers.com/) from the php script (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do it was to use [MailConverter](https://www.coolutils.com/TotalMailConverter) command line on a Windows server to process the file into HTML.  The program is ~$60.

First, using the MailConverter command line generator, you create a template batch file so you can process any file.  I changed the actual file names with two placeholders, [[SOURCE]] and [[DESTINATION]].

```
chcp 65001
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CoolUtils\TotalMailConverter\MailConverter.exe" "[[SOURCE]]" "[[DESTINATION]]" -kfs -c XHTML -template [name] -body -clearsubj -timeout 10000 -dpi 300 -pc M -PDFAuthor Softplicity -PDFProducer Softplicity -TM 0.3 -LM 0.3 -BM 0.3 -RM 0.3 -ps A4 -tc G4 -tjq 80 -multipage -HeadText "Page [page]" -HeadAlign c -HeadFont Tahoma -HeadSize 10 -FootText [date] -FootAlign c -FootFont Tahoma -FootSize 10 -toclinestyle D -toclinecolor silver -tocfont [Calibri,11,black] -tocmargins [0.80,0.80,0.80,0.80] -dco [TOC]
```

Then the php code replaces the placeholders and generates the final batch file, then runs it to output the html.  This code currently in production environment.

It will hang up if you try to process the same output file twice, so you have to check if the output file exists first.

```
<?php
        $filename = "template.bat";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);

        //any name ok for output
        $new_path = str_replace(".msg", "converted.html", $path);

        if (!file_exists($new_path)) {
            $new_content = str_replace("[[SOURCE]]", $path, $contents);
            $new_content = str_replace("[[DESTINATION]]", $new_path, $new_content);

            //write the new batch command to a new file
            $fp = fopen('convert.bat', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, $new_content);
            fclose($fp);

            //run the batch file
            passthru ('convert.bat');
            //wait a couple of seconds to let the exe process the file
            sleep(2);
        }

        $filename = $new_path;
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);

        die($contents);
?>
```